# Sort table by header

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I want to be able to sort table by clicking on the headers.  I have found some examples online of how to do this but when I try to follow them I get errors.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the PHP code that I use to create the tables from MySQL.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$Town = $_POST['Town'];
$Range = $_POST['Range'];
$Section = $_POST['Section'];

$con = mysql_connect('server, 'database', 'password');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ncwrpc", $con);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `index8` WHERE `MAPID` = $Town$Range$Section LIMIT 0, 500 ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table border='2' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='2' bordercolor='#000000' bgcolor='#B8B8B8' >
<tr>

<h2>TOWN: $Town N - RANGE: $Range E - SECTION: $Section</h2>
<th bgcolor=\"#669999\">MAP</th>
<th bgcolor=\"#669999\">DESC. 1</th>
<th bgcolor=\"#669999\">DESC. 2</th>
<th bgcolor=\"#669999\">REMARKS</th>
<th bgcolor=\"#669999\">SURVEYOR</th>
<th bgcolor=\"#669999\">CLIENT</th>
<th bgcolor=\"#669999\">YEAR</th>
</tr>";

$color = "0"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    if($color == "0"){ 
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><a href=\"".$row['LINK']."\" target=\"_blank\">".$row['MAP1']."</a></td>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['Desc1'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['Desc2'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['Remarks'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['Surveyor'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['Client'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['Y'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "</tr>"; 
        $color = "1"; 
    }else{ 
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFF380\"><a href=\"".$row['LINK']."\" target=\"_blank\">".$row['MAP1']."</a></td>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFF380\">" . $row['Desc1'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFF380\">" . $row['Desc2'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFF380\">" . $row['Remarks'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFF380\">" . $row['Surveyor'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFF380\">" . $row['Client'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFF380\">" . $row['Y'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "</tr>"; 
        $color = "0"; 
    } 
}  


?>
```

Comment: When you write "I've got errors" you should say where and what errors they are. And don't say "in line no. 5" because we don't know which line is line no. 5.

Comment: You are missing an apostrophe here `$con = mysql_connect('server, 'database', 'password');`

Comment: there are no errors above it works fine. Just want to add the sorting.  Yes there is a error with the mysql _connect as mentioned I just removed the server name and etc. from this post.  I will look into the jquery as suggested below.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to have a look at jQuery datatables (http://www.datatables.net/) does this job and much more for you out of the box.

if your really want to solve it in mysql, just add a `SORT BY field` (where `field` is a placeholder for your field you want to sort by) to your sql query. then you can add this field to your sort-link in the html code.

Answer (score 2):

you can sort the data by simple manipulating the html,using jquery, there is a plenity of free plugins like [this](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo) in this way is much simplier, faster and cost less request to your server